# How to add two output expressions to calculate the third expression in Cadence icfb 5?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, cadence

I am trying to calculate the average propagation time carry_TP from carry_TPHL and carry_TPLH which I already got the expression from the calculator tool and works well. Now how do I make the third output expression for carry_TP = (carry_TPHL+carrt_TPLH)/2? What I have tried (shown in image) isn't working for me. I am using the cadence icfb version 5.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot, it looks like you're summing `carry_TPLH` twice?

If the problem you've got is format related, I know in Virtuoso IC6 and upwards that you can do `(carry_TPLH + carry_TPHL)/2`, but alternatively you could try the `calcVal` function:

`(calcVal("carry_TPLH" "your_test") + calcVal("carry_TPHL" "your_test"))/2`